# Making wget to bypass index.html file

Tags: wget

I am trying to download all the images from [this link](http://indiabix.com/civil-engineering/hydraulics/). I want to download images from only the hydraulics section, so I used `--no-parent` and when I run the command

`wget -r --no-parent -e robots=off --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" -A png http://indiabix.com/civil-engineering/hydraulics/`

it only downloads the index.html.

I searched this issue on the web, and Stack Overflow already has two questions:

- [wget downloads only one index.html file instead of other some 500 html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434173/wget-downloads-only-one-index-html-file-instead-of-other-some-500-html-files)
- [Why does wget only download the index.html for some websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124292/why-does-wget-only-download-the-index-html-for-some-websites)

but they do not help. I also started a bounty on the latter question, but I wonder if anyone can suggest a workaround in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple:

- there are no images on the link you provided.

The tiny icons ("View Answer" etc.) are part of a CSS definition for the anchor (background-image). As per now, wget will not parse the external CSS and pick images from there.

With -A png wget will even stop at the first file (.html) since it doesn't match.

I've succeded downloading everything with

```
   lwp-rget --hier --nospace http://indiabix.com/civil-engineering/hydraulics/
```

The lwp CPAN perl packages need to be installed: `zypper se libwww`

Comment: But it should follow the links and switch to other sections and there are images inbetween the questions . For example, on the link I provided, it should visit and then select page 2 at the bottom menu or select different sections from the left sidebar

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on knowing the path to the images folder, so that it can be added to the list of directories to be included (without the `--include` parameter the whole site will be fetched).

`wget 'http://indiabix.com/civil-engineering/hydraulics/' --convert-links --adjust-extension --recursive --page-requisites --no-directories --directory-prefix=output --include '/civil-engineering/hydraulics','/_files/images'`