# Why can't Wget recursive download all files at this address? (solution found, but not sure why this works)

Tags: wget

I was trying to download a nice dataset from this URL.

https://pubs.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9

using the referenced command listed
https://diabimmune.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/t1d-cohort/resources/16s-sequence-data

Alas, it was only returning the index file.

I'm not one to give up, and after several hours search I came across this post
[wget downloads only one index.html file instead of other some 500 html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434173/wget-downloads-only-one-index-html-file-instead-of-other-some-500-html-files)

Whose solution worked wonders (so far, still downloading haha)

I don't understand why this is though, the link used as an example in the above post is dead, so I'm not sure what the domain issue is, or how I can avoid this in future, I gather the -rH parameter can wreak havoc if improperly used.

I'm not a computer science major so any insight would be really appreciated.

Cheers.

wget -r -np -nd https://pubs.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9/ -H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not a computer science major so any insight would be really
> appreciated.

First important thing is understand what host is, parts of URL according to [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) are

```
//<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
```

user, password, @, port and path are optional, so if you have URL

```
https://pubs.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9
```

then host is

```
pubs.broadinstitute.org
```

One might get information about link using `--spider` option of GNU wget

```
wget --spider https://pubs.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9
```

will provide output, important parts are

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://diabimmune.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9 [following]
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://diabimmune.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9/ [following]
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 298054 (291K) [text/html]
Remote file exists
```

Status code [301](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) and [302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) are redirects, observe that now host is different - `diabimmune.broadinstitute.org` - however if you download it, it does contain links with `pubs.broadinstitute.org` host, therefore GNU `wget` does not retrieve them.

> how I can avoid this in future, I gather the -rH parameter can wreak
> havoc if improperly used.

This might give effect of downloading files you actually do not need, so problems which might arise from that are clogging network connection or your disk space. [Spanning Hosts](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html) suggest combining `-rH` with `-D` to get only domain you actually wants, in your case that might be

```
wget -rH -Dbroadinstitute.org -np -nd https://pubs.broadinstitute.org/diabimmune/data/9/
```

Observe that there `broadinstitute.org` means retrieve if domain ends with `broadinstitute.org`, which is true for both `pubs.broadinstitute.org` and `diabimmune.broadinstitute.org`

Comment: Hey man, really appreciate the response here! Very insightful. Thanks for clarifying! :)